# Can we schedule Selenium test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created Selenium Web Driver test cases and running it in Maven.

Can we schedule Selenium test cases to run at user-given date/time.

I googled and found few options like (1) creating a batch file & then adding it in Windows scheduler or (2) Using Jenkins

Somewhere, Quartz Scheduler was given.

Is there any other better method for it or which is the best method among these options.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

We use Jenkins since it offers a variety of options to connect to different source control systems, allows building your requirement in variety of ways using scripts, maven commands, ant etc.  You can create dependent jobs, use variety of plugins that add additional functionality to Jenkins, share reports, send emails ....and can schedule jobs on a variety of parameters as well like based on time or based on a commit in your repo or based on your build being deployed.  I haven't used Quartz scheduler, so no opinions on that.

Comment: Thanks but I want to know about Quartz also.